# VSTS CI/CD solution with multiple sites

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline for our project on VSTS.

The project, or better to say the solution consists of 4 websites (ASP.NET hosted on virtual machines) and 5 additional shared projects. At the moment whenever we push something to git a build process is triggered and VSTS builds the whole solution all 4 websites.

I have a few questions

- I haven't managed to find which project configuration CI uses for build. does it switches automatically to release mode or uses whatever is selected during checkout (e.g. Debug). If doesn't switch to release mode is it possible to force it somehow?
- Ideally, I would like to pick up which website is going to be built in order to save time and of course, once the build is over only to deploy that site to staging/live environment not all 4. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Specifying the Solution Configuration.

The *Visual Studio Build* and the *MsBuild* tasks have a Platform and Configuration parameter which can force the correct configuration:

[image]

The most common trick is to set a variable here so that you can specify these values on the Visual Studio Test task as well.

If you leave these empty it will default to the Solution default, which could be anything.

### Incremental Build

To only build/deploy the changes projects you need to configure the build to build incrementally. To do so make sure that the build agent retains the workspace, doesn't perform a clean build.

That way MsBuild can detect which files have changed and what needs to be rebuilt.

You'll then probably need to look at the dates of the output files to detect which sites to deploy.

While this may save you a little bit of time, it also introduces some chances for inconsistencies. Be careful. This may work fine to reduce the build times of your CI build, but for CD I'd rely on a clean build, just to make sure no left-overs from a previous build ends up being released when it shouldn't.

[Some tips from a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164692/736079).

### Alternative

An alternative to incremental builds would consist of detecting the changes since the last successful build. While theoretically possible, there is no out-of-the-box script and the way project files and solution files can reference items outside of their root folder can make this impossible, unless the solution was designed to work correctly from the ground up. Your post doesn't mention the type of repository (Git or TFVC), depending on your setup you may be able to query the Build API (through PowerShell and REST) to fetch the last changeset/commit that resulted in a successful build, use that information to diff against the current repo state and then decide what to do.