# VSTS Multiple Build Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have installed 3 build agents on 2 core 8 GB ram and after that, it takes time to build the job as I am building the JAR file from this job so my question is if I purchase high-end server will it increase the performance or any solution for multiple build agent configuration.

When I am running 3 build agent its takes 25-30 min to build and single build agent takes 5-10 minute.

Comment: how much time does the build take on a normal local machine?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is more related--how to speed up the builds. Will the hardware of build server improved effect your build speed? Definitely.

> To really speed up, you'll need to setup your own build server. Using
>   a DS Azure VM running on a permanent **SSD** will give you the most
>   performance benefit.

Since you are using multiple agents in one machine. You might also want to

> Parallelize your builds. If you're building multiple projects or
>   multiple configurations make use of the ability to MultiConfiguration
>   option to spin up multiple builds on multiple agents (you do need to
>   allocate multiple hosted agents in this case)

[image]

And  [Phases in Build and Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/phases?view=vsts)

Besides there are multiple ways to improve the build speed, reduce build execution time. Suggest you take a look at the wonderful answer from *jessehouwing* in related question: [Is there a way to speed up the builds in visual studio team services (and TFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811818/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-the-builds-in-visual-studio-team-services-and-tfs)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer now I am planning for 6 build agents to run parallel so which configuration is suitable for this is it DS server on Azure is enough.these agents are not on dockers.

Comment: @RohanKhanolkar We will not and can't recommend  you detailed configuration. Couldn't judge whether it's enough or not for you. However, you could just follow the tutorials in above link, which will definitely speed up your original builds.  If my reply helped or gave a right direction, appreciate for marking it as an answer.

Comment: Great answer @PatrickLu-MSFT. Would vote it twice if I could.

Comment: @ PatrickLu-MSFT : nope issue is still the same as the server configuration is needed to upgrade the same to resolve the issue.

Comment: @RohanKhanolkar Thanks for the feed back, once your server upgraded and the issue fixed free feel to share here. About the detail server configuration, we could not judge which is applicable to your company. You may upgrade by your company's requirement.